# Trying to start a service on boot on Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I've been trying to start a service when a device boots up on android, but I cannot get it to work. I've looked at a number of links online but none of the code works. Am I forgetting something?

#### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver
    android:name=".StartServiceAtBootReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false"
    android:label="StartServiceAtBootReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action._BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service
    android:name="com.test.RunService"
    android:enabled="true" />
```

#### BroadcastReceiver

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Intent serviceLauncher = new Intent(context, RunService.class);
        context.startService(serviceLauncher);
        Log.v("TEST", "Service loaded at start");
    }
}
```

Comment: i dunno what i did but i think it works now it might have been the 
android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" for the receiver

Comment: have you checked the extra "_" in <action android:name="android.intent.action._BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

Comment: Exported must be true so system can invoke the receiver, no? Or is it true by default?

Comment: for Oreo, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44502229/runtime-exception-android-o-with-boot-completed

Answer (score 611):

The other answers look good, but I thought I'd wrap everything up into one complete answer.

You need the following in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

1. In your `<manifest>` element:

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
   ```
2. In your `<application>` element (be sure to use a fully-qualified [or relative] class name for your `BroadcastReceiver`):

   ```
   <receiver android:name="com.example.MyBroadcastReceiver">  
       <intent-filter>  
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
       </intent-filter>  
   </receiver>
   ```

   (you don't need the `android:enabled`, `exported`, etc., attributes: the Android defaults are correct)

   In `MyBroadcastReceiver.java`:

   ```
   package com.example;

   public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
           context.startService(startServiceIntent);
       }
   }
   ```

From the original question:

- it's not clear if the `<receiver>` element was in the `<application>` element
- it's not clear if the correct fully-qualified (or relative) class name for the `BroadcastReceiver` was specified
- there was a typo in the `<intent-filter>`

Comment: This looks good. I'm gonna use this as a basis, thanks :). No checkmark or upvotes or response sadly :(. Anyone verify this?

Comment: Just a complement: make sure your app is install in internal memory 

<manifest xmlns:android="..."
 package="..." android:installLocation="internalOnly">

Comment: Its very simple and perfect, Just i saw the answer once , i wont forgot ever.

Comment: In Android Jellybean 4.2.2 in the <receiver> tag I had to use the class' relative name instead of the fully-qualified name for the service to start, as noted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16671619/android-intentservice-wont-start-on-boot

Comment: If the receiver is used for different stuff:<br>
  if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
   Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, Service_Location.class);
   // i.putExtra("KEY1", "Value to be used by the service");
   context.startService(serviceIntent);
  }

Comment: Can I then stop the receiver from the Activity in the same project? That is, does broadcast receiver start a process, to which service belongs, and also the activities that I can start? That is - if I firstly create service, from an activity, and I can stop it from that activity, and then I reboot and start the same service on startup, can I use the Activity to stop it, like in the first case?

Comment: You should extend https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html instead. It is a Helper for the common pattern of implementing a BroadcastReceiver that receives a device wakeup event and then passes the work off to a Service, while ensuring that the device does not go back to sleep during the transition.

This class takes care of creating and managing a partial wake lock for you; you must request the WAKE_LOCK permission to use it.

Comment: I made an application that contains all the aspects mentioned in your answer. Nevertheless it does not work on my Nexus 5 running Android 5.0.1 although it does work on a Nexus 5 Android 5.0.1 emulator and a Samsung GT-I9100 running Android 4.1.2. What could be wrong with my Nexus?

Comment: I am having the same problem. Do you mind helping me? Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35373525/starting-my-service

Comment: @BaoLe this is the default, so you don't need to specify. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#install

Comment: for Oreo, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44502229/runtime-exception-android-o-with-boot-completed

Answer (score 85):

As an additional info: BOOT_COMPLETE is sent to applications *before* external storage is mounted. So if application is installed to external storage it won't receive BOOT_COMPLETE broadcast message.

More details [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html) in section ***Broadcast Receivers listening for "boot completed"***

Comment: To prevent the above issue, the developer could set "android:installLocation="internalOnly" in the manifest for an app.  Is that a bad idea?  For a smartphone app, if 99.9% (my guess) of all users install the app normally, by using internal storage rather than external storage, then it seems the "internalOnly" addition to the manifest would be fine.  I would appreciate any thoughts or ideas you have on this.

Answer (score 70):

How to start service on device boot(autorun app, etc.)

For first: since version Android 3.1+ you don't receive BOOT_COMPLETE if user never started your app at least once or user "force closed" application.
This was done to prevent malware automatically register service. This security hole was closed in newer versions of Android.

Solution:

Create app with activity. When user run it once app can receive BOOT_COMPLETE broadcast message.

For second: BOOT_COMPLETE is sent before external storage is mounted. If app is installed to external storage it won't receive BOOT_COMPLETE broadcast message.

In this case there is two solution:

1. Install your app to internal storage
2. Install another small app in internal storage. This app receives BOOT_COMPLETE and run second app on external storage.

If your app already installed in internal storage then code below can help you understand how to start service on device boot.

---

In Manifest.xml

Permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Register your BOOT_COMPLETED receiver:

```
<receiver android:name="org.yourapp.OnBoot">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Register your service:

```
<service android:name="org.yourapp.YourCoolService" />
```

---

In receiver OnBoot.java:

```
public class OnBoot extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        // Create Intent
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, YourCoolService.class);
        // Start service
        context.startService(serviceIntent);

    }

 }
```

---

For HTC you maybe need also add in Manifest this code if device don't catch RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
```

Receiver now look like this:

```
<receiver android:name="org.yourapp.OnBoot">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

---

How to test BOOT_COMPLETED without restart emulator or real device?
It's easy. Try this:

```
adb -s device-or-emulator-id shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
```

How to get device id? Get list of connected devices with id's:

```
adb devices
```

adb in ADT by default you can find in:

```
adt-installation-dir/sdk/platform-tools
```

Enjoy! )

Comment: Your first paragraph was capital. I was unable to make it run in my debugger.

Answer (score 34):

Along with

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

also use,

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
```

HTC devices dont seem to catch BOOT_COMPLETED

Comment: Need to add anything similar in permissions for HTC devices ?

Comment: This could be useful in some circumstances, but I understand the HTC Fast Boot is a form of hibernation where system state is saved to the filesystem, and the `android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON` is only sent when restoring from fast boot. This means it isn't necessary to do things like resetting alarms when recovering from Fast Boot as they are preserved. Therefore it would only be necessary to use `<action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />` if you want to do something when the user thinks the device has booted.

Comment: From a app developer's perspective, we should never use this, if the behaviour exists only on HTC devices. Because, BOOT_COMPLETED is, as per the documentation, will always be sent when the device turns ON. Some other manufacturer could come up with another method of fast booting and we would end up messing our code with each one's specifications.

Comment: @HexAndBugs Were you able to confirm that Fast Boot is a form of hibernation where system state is saved to the filesystem?  I want to be able to reset alarms that are used for future Notifications after a Fast Boot if system state is not saved...please advise.

Answer (score 20):

note that at the beginning of the question, there is a typo mistake:

`<action android:name="android.intent.action._BOOT_COMPLETED"/>`

instead of :

`<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>`

one small "_" and all this trouble :)

Answer (score 13):

I think your manifest needs to add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Comment: I am having the same problem. Do you mind helping me? Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35373525/starting-my-service

Answer (score 13):

I found out just now that it might be because of `Fast Boot` option in `Settings` > `Power`

When I have this option off, my application receives a this broadcast but not otherwise.

By the way, I have `Android 2.3.3` on `HTC Incredible S`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Definitely possible cause of the issue. Observed also on HTC Desire C running Android 4.0.3.

Answer (score 7):

After trying all of mentioned answers and tricks, I finally find why the code is not work in my phone. Some Android phones like "Huawei Honor 3C **Android  4.2.2**" have a **Statup Manager** menu in their settings and your app must be checked in the list. 
:)

Answer (score 5):

I have an additional `<category>`-tag, don't know if that makes any difference.

```
<receiver android:name="BootIntentReceiver">  
        <intent-filter>  
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />  
        </intent-filter>  
</receiver>
```

Have you tried ommiting the if-clause `"android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction()`, as the receiver probably only receives that intent anyway?

Comment: tried this and it didn't work btw i forgot to mention i also have the

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

Comment: just in case: adding android.intent.category.HOME to any tag in the AndroidManifest will cause the Samsung Galaxy Tab to run the app in compatibility mode, even after using the hack to turn compatibility mode off.  not sure if this is the same for other tabs.  i recommend not setting the HOME category at all.  it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I did

**1. I made the Receiver class**

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //whatever you want to do on boot
       Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, YourService.class);
       context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

**2.in the manifest**

```
<manifest...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <application...>
        <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    ...
```

**3.and after ALL you NEED to "set" the receiver in your MainActivity, it may be inside the onCreate**

```
...
 final ComponentName onBootReceiver = new ComponentName(getApplication().getPackageName(), BootReceiver.class.getName());
        if(getPackageManager().getComponentEnabledSetting(onBootReceiver) != PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED)
        getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(onBootReceiver,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
...
```

the final steap I have learned from ApiDemos

Comment: you should check for the incoming intent on your `onReceive` method (`BOOT_COMPLETED`), otherwise, your app will be called from suspicious apps installed on your device.

Answer (score 4):

Refer This Link http://khurramitdeveloper.blogspot.in/2013/06/start-activity-or-service-on-boot.html
Step by Step procedure to use boot on Service

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Android Studio and you're very fond of auto-complete then I must inform you, I'm using Android Studio v 1.1.0 and I used auto-complete for the following permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

And Android Studio Auto-completed`RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` all in lower-case like `receive_boot_completed` and I kept pulling my hair out because I'd already ticked out my checklist for things to do to start service at boot. I just confirmed again

> Android Studio DOES auto-complete this permission in lower-case.

Answer (score 2):

As @Damian commented, all the answers in this thread are doing it wrong. Doing it manually like this runs the risk of your Service being stopped in the middle from the device going to sleep. You need to obtain a wake lock first. Luckily, the [Support library gives us a class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html#completeWakefulIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) to do this:

```
public class SimpleWakefulReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // This is the Intent to deliver to our service.
        Intent service = new Intent(context, SimpleWakefulService.class);

        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        Log.i("SimpleWakefulReceiver", "Starting service @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        startWakefulService(context, service);
    }
}
```

then, in your Service, make sure to release the wake lock:

```
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // At this point SimpleWakefulReceiver is still holding a wake lock
        // for us.  We can do whatever we need to here and then tell it that
        // it can release the wakelock.

...
        Log.i("SimpleWakefulReceiver", "Completed service @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        SimpleWakefulReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
```

Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permssion to your mainfest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: Little question i have a doubt. If my _service_ is a **Service** and not **IntentService** i can not use this way, because **onHandleIntend** method can not be _override_ in simple **Service**?

Comment: I am having the same problem. Do you mind helping me? Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35373525/starting-my-service

Comment: Maybe use `onNewIntent()`? Or you could look at the source for IntentService and see what you need to do for your Service to make it match...

Answer (score 1):

In fact,I get into this trouble not long ago,and it's really really easy to fix,you actually do nothing wrong if you setup the `"android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"` permission and intent-filter.

Be attention that if you On Android 4.X,you have to run the broadcast listener before you start service on boot,that means,you have to add an activity first,once your broadcast receiver running,your app should function as you expected,however,on Android 4.X,I haven't found a way to start the service on boot without any activity,I think google did that for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with this problem if i leave the empty constructor in the  receiver class. After the removing the empty contsructor onRreceive methos started working fine.